# UIButton not showing complete title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Iam dynamically generating UIButton and when i set title name without space its showing correctly.
For eg:

```
NSString *myString=[[array valueForKey:@"optionName"] objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@",myString); // myString=SampleTitle
[button setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and when i set name with space its auto trimming UIButton title.
For eg:

```
NSString *myString=[[array valueForKey:@"optionName"] objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@",myString); // myString=SampleTitle Test
[button setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Its showing like this

[image]

HOw can i remove this trimming part? i need to show all characters properly.

and my UIButton size is calculating based on title

```
[button setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGSize stringsize = [@"Prolonged inspiration" sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        //or whatever font you're using
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize.width+30,stringsize.height+20)];
```

Comment: You need to make the button bigger or use a smaller font.

Comment: button size is based on string length

Comment: Update your question with how you determine the button size.

Comment: updated ..please chekc now

Comment: 1) The `sizeWithFont:` method is deprecated. 2) Why not use the button's font instead of specifying some other font?

Comment: i didnt understand can u show some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your issue is that you calculate the size of the text using a font that is likely different from the button's font. Base your calculation on the button's font as well as the button's text.

```
CGSize stringsize = [myString sizeWithFont:button.titleLabel.font];
```

As a side note, the `sizeWithFont:` method was deprecated back in iOS 7.0. Unless you are also supporting iOS 6, you should replace that method with the proper replacement.

Comment: Its working...thanks... but it showing deprecated so is there any other way too?

Comment: is there any way to increase my cell height based on these dynamic buttons?

Comment: That's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iOS versions above iOS 7.0

```
CGSize textSize = { widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX };            
CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:textSize
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font }
                                      context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+1);
```